# how to make ajax function wait until all result reveive for callback function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am reading URLs of images from XML file in Ajax function with async set to false, so it should wait for Ajax function to complete. while receiving these URL, i am calling another function to validate if URL has valid image, and i receive Boolean value from callback function " isUrlIsImage()"... however i have discover Ajax doesn't wait for all result receive from callback function... anyone knows where to look??? how can i enforce Ajax to wait for all callback function ... many thanks in advance...

```
$.fn.initializeImg = function (CP_ID) {

var selected_dataType = "";

if (currentBrowser().browser == "IE" && currentBrowser().version < 10) {

    selected_dataType = "text";
}
else {
    selected_dataType = "xml";
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "XML_file.xml",
    dataType:  selected_dataType,
    async:false,
    success: function (xml) {

        var processedXML_01 = parseXml(xml);


      $(processedXML_01).find('property').each(function () {

      var j_propertyIn_List = $(this).find('propcode').text();

           if (j_propertyIn_List == gb_var.j_propcode) {

       $(this).find('photo').each(function (index) {

       gb_var.j_propertyImgURLs[index] = $(this).find('urlname');

     console.log(">>>>   "+gb_var.j_propertyImgURLs[index].text());

      isUrlIsImage(gb_var.j_propertyImgURLs[index].text(), function (_url, result) {

    //alert("check result >> "+result + " for " + _url);

     if (result) {

      console.log("******TRUE*********  check result >> " + result + " for " + _url);

     }
     else {
      console.log("******FALSE*********  check result >> " + result + " for " + _url);

                       }
                   });
               });
            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
    }

  });

  } //end plugin function 

  })(jQuery);


function isUrlIsImage(given_url, callback) {

console.log(" checking............. " + given_url);

url = given_url;

   $("<img>", {
       src: url,
       error: function () { callback(url, false); },
       load: function () { callback(url, true); }
      });
  }
```

Comment: have you seen http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax? it has this amazing thing where it tells you all the options. One of them is `async`, I think you should check it out.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this synchronously?  The async option has been deprecated since v1.8.

Comment: `async:false` is a bad idea unless you fully understand its implications. If your server doesn't respond quickly it will hang up the page completely, and in some browsers it will hang up other pages as well. `async:false` is really a last resort and shouldn't be the first thing you reach for.

Comment: the reason why I am doing async:false because in case of true return from isUrlIsImage(given_url, callback) method, i will create dynamic content ; li tag and append url in it... now i need to ensure it all finish before 2nd plugin is called i.e. DYNAMIC CONTENTS ARE READY BEFORE DOM ... now becuase img checking in url takes more time and ajax function doesnt wait ... my whole logic fail... i need to ensure i receive all isUrlIsImage(given_url, callback) results before ajax ends